# How to find value that have some charcter in third position?

Tags: sql

I Couldn't find the value that has 'r' in the third position using LIKE operation in SQL.
could anyone help me, please?

Comment: I don't agree with the flag `duplicate`. Only a part of this is question seems like duplicate...

Comment: @OP- You need to provide us what you have done already. Plus we don't know what DBMS you are talking about. Handling problems like this is highly dependent on the DBMS that you are using. And, your question is far too less descriptive. Please refine your question...

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better to write something like this.

```
SELECT <column>, FROM <table> WHERE <condition> LIKE "__r%";
```

EDIT:
This is tested and functional for SQL Server and Oracle DBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE substring(<column>,3,1) = 'r'
```

Try this. This is using SQL Server which will yield the result you are looking for.

Comment: Which DBMS are you referring to? I am pretty sure that this is not something that is universal to all DBMSs. You need to provide specific details..

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the r from 'scr' with position 3

Try this

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '__r%';

position is count of _.

Comment: for example   image that word is 'wefdkeifs'.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName LIKE '__r%';    If you use this query ,result will zero.because there is no 'r' in the third position.

Comment: Or not,if word is 'scr'  result is not zero(>0)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: you can use this url .